# KLT tracker implementation

Tags: image-processing, matlab, object-recognition, matlab-cvst, visual-tracking

I'm working on a object tracker based on KLT algorithm using matlab.
Can anybody guide me how I can find the features and calculate the distance in the sequence of the frames?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [example of tracking a single face using KLT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html).  Try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47105-detect-and-track-multiple-faces) for tracking multiple faces.

Comment: Hi Dima. I was looking for implementing the algorithm for tracking vehicles from the aerial platform. any help on this?